# 503 error with urllib and flask

Tags: python, json, heroku, urllib2

When i run this Heroku app in debug mode, it works perfectly, but when I push the changes and visit the page, the page refuses to load and i get a 503 error. I can't figure out what is wrong (seeing as how debug says everything is fine :( ) [using python 2.7]

fixed. see comment

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I fixed it. All i did was I referenced the local json file on my computer rather than the url.